# Current script path with type="module"

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm trying to access a file that I want to reference relative to a script file while using `<script type="module">`. Normally, without type="module", people seem to be looking up the script tag and using its src attribute to get the path, but this obviously isn't possible after using imports.

The scenario looks roughly like this:

File structure:

```
js/
    script.js
    other/
        imported.js
index.html
```

index.html:

```
<html><head><script type="module" src="js/script.js"></script></head></html>
```

script.js

```
import "other/imported.js";
```

imported.js

```
// ??? should with some code magic become "js/other/imported.js" or similar
console.log("The path to this script is: " + "???");
```

I saw some thread somewhere where it was discussed that the reason `document.currentScript` is `null` when using `type="module"` is because they wanted to figure out a better alternative. I suppose this alternative is not yet available?

So, to recap, with the file structure above, how can one find the path to js/other/imported.js in that script dynamically?

Comment: Are there browsers that support module imports today? You probably need to say which browser you using to get a valid answer.

Comment: I was thinking to have the answer be at least somewhat standard compliant, but right now, I'm using chrome beta (60) to test and will probably verify with Firefox and maybe safari that everything works.

Answer (score 8):

To answer my own question almost 2 years later, there's now a thing called `import.meta` which is used to provide arbitrary information about the current module. In this case, `import.meta.url` would be the thing I was looking for.

You can read more on this MDN page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta